# Are goal-reaching and optimizing the utility function special cases of performance measure?

Tags: intelligent-agent, performance, goal-based-agents, utility-based-agents, rational-agents

In AIMA, *performance measure* is defined as something evaluating the behavior of the agent in an environment.

*Rational agents* are defined as agents acting so as to maximize the expected value of the performance measure, given the percept sequence they have seen so far.

*Goal-based agents* are those acting to achieve their goals. *Utility-based agents* are those trying to maximize their own expected "happiness".

Now, can we say these two design approaches induce performance measures?

What I suggest is that in goal-based agent design we want to find a point satisfying some conditions, so it's an optimization problem with a zero objective function and either this function is the performance measure or performance measure is optimized if and only if we find a solution to this optimization problem with zero objective function. In the utility-based agent design, we have an objective function (as a performance measure) that we want to optimize, and the agent has its own utility function, which it wants to optimize, and this utility function is optimized if and only if our objective function is optimized.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?